# What's the best way to restrict insert/update queries when using ExecuteSqlCommand?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm inheriting a class that has this public virtual method

```
public virtual int ExecuteSqlCommand(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters);
}
```

I want to override it and provide read-only access to the database, so any Insert/Update commands should be restricted

I can do it by searching for the insert/update keywords in the query, but I'm not sure this is 100% proof.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes -- don't give the account(s) accessing the database permission to change anything (and/or create an alternate account for those accesses only). This is the *only* fool-proof method short of using a fully featured T-SQL parser on the command, and even if you did that you would not be able to tell if (say) a stored procedure call updates anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the database security handle it. Run the queries with a user account that only has read permission to the database.

You could use your method of searching for insert/update if you want to warn the user in advance, but I wouldn't rely on it as a security mechanism. At that point you may as well run the query and handle the error if they have insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE is not 100% proof if consumers want really to misuse it
They can execute something like:

```
EXEC('DE' + 'LETE ' + 'FROM Users')
```

Another way that also basically works but not proof is to create a transaction and roll it back at the end.

The best way would be to create a new user with only read-only access and connect to the database using that user account.

Comment: Another way is to create triggers that rollback the changes although this seems foolproof but it takes effort to create triggers on all tables